# WPF LIstview rows stay selected when button rows clicked

Tags: wpf, listview

I have a button in a Listview column. In order for the entire row to select when the button is pressed, I use this code:

```
        private void ButtonClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            ListViewItem selectedRow = GetAncestorOfType<ListViewItem>(sender as Button);
            selectedRow.IsSelected = true;
        }

        public T GetAncestorOfType<T>(FrameworkElement child) where T : FrameworkElement
        {
            var parent = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(child);
            if (parent != null && !(parent is T))
                return (T)GetAncestorOfType<T>((FrameworkElement)parent);
            return (T)parent;
        }
```

This all works great, but if I click the button in one row, then click the button in another row, both rows stay selected. I thought about going through and manually deselecting all rows every time a button is clicked, but I do need to be able to select multiple rows if ctrl is held down. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using [`UnselectAll`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.listbox.unselectall(v=vs.110).aspx) on the `ListView` before updating the selection:

```
private void ButtonClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    myListView.UnselectAll();

    ListViewItem selectedRow = GetAncestorOfType<ListViewItem>(sender as Button);
    selectedRow.IsSelected = true;
}
```